# Is Lambda Proxy Integration a reverse proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-lambda

Say there is a client X, a proxy server Y (like API Gateway), and server Z (like a lambda function), and lambda proxy integration is enabled for the resource the client is connecting to.

Since X is intending to communicate with Z, but does not know about Z and must instead communicate with Y, who then communicates with Z, is Y acting like a reverse proxy in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, API Gateways (AWS or otherwise) in general are a type of reverse proxy.

Reverse proxies route requests from external clients to internal services, which is exactly what AWS API Gateway is doing in your scenario (see image below).

[image: Reverse Proxy]

Image taken from [this](https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/87783/Forward-Proxy-vs-Reverse-Proxy) article, which gives a decent description of forward and reverse proxies (while plugging the publishers own products).